# co generator yield not working with mongoclient

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, generator, co

```
const Db = require('mongodb').Db;
const Server = require('mongodb').Server;
const co = require('co');

const v1Db = new Db('v2-staging', new Server('localhost', 27017));

function* migrateBatch() {
  const collectionV1Uploadfile = yield v1Db.collection('test');

  return {};
}

co(migrateBatch()).then((data) => {
  console.log('end of process');
});
```

> Im using nodejs- v6.9.4
>       mongo - v3.4.0 version.
>   and gettig the following error. even though mongo documentation says it returns object a collection instance.
>   [mongo documentation reference](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#collection)
>
> **ERROR** (node:96130) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: You may only yi // eld a
>   function, promise, generator, array, or object, but the following
>   object was passed: "[object Object]"

Comment: Yes, a "collection instance" is not a "function, promise or generator". Either don't yield it, or get a promise for the result when you're doing something asynchronous (doesn't look like it).

Comment: For one, you are pointing to the old documentation, [here's new stuff](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#find). Kind of clearly points out the context you would use an generator in.

Comment: please specify reason for downvote!

Comment: @bergi but I need to make sure that collection instance is created while performing further operation, thats why i've used **yield**  .Also, a "collection instance" is a "Object" indeed.
Is there any other way to work around and i don't want to write callback.

Comment: What do you mean, "while performing further operation"? The `Collection` constructor is synchronous, and so is [`db.collection`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Db.html#collection) when not passing a callback in non-strict mode. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to return a promise in asynchronous mode.

Comment: No, "objects" refers to [collections of yieldables that are awaited in parallel](https://github.com/tj/co#objects). You cannot await a `Collection` instance.